# Screen Turns Off after Ubuntu Login - New Install

Tags: debian, ubuntu

Booting from the live USB, UEFI, I can use Ubuntu. I install to my SSD, with "Install 3rd party drivers" and reboot.

I get presented with the Ubuntu login screen, but the mouse movements are incredibly jerky. After logging in, my monitor goes to sleep.

I have tried various methods, and have wasted countless hours. This involved...
Various boot options
Boot repair
Hitting escape tab and a plethora of ineffectual keys at startup

My question is... why does the live screen have no issue, but the full install won't drive my monitor?

Edit: GPU is G200eR2

Same issue as this person https://askubuntu.com/questions/875238/how-to-add-a-graphics-card-driver

I was able to get SSH up and running and super slow refresh full resolution. It's almost unusable.

Comment: maybe SSD failure

Comment: Tried two SSDs. But quite observant. It is indeed one thing that's different.

Comment: If you are using the Nvidia drivers, try swapping them out for Nouveau, at least temporarily, to see if that helps at all. Ive had all kinds of problems with the proprietary module lately (from about 470 on) including the one you are describing. I ended up switching back to Nouveau for now.

Comment: Do you get a small white blinking cursor prompt in the corner? If not, go to a TTY and wait it out for a few minutes. Then switch back to TTY1. Adding another user and logging in that way also helps in some cases. If it is a new install, this may be the best option for you.

Comment: Fixed seems it was RAM... still no idea why the live boot USB worked and the main install didn't.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Seems "nomodeset" brought back the screen. Wasn't RAM after all.

Comment: @NateT - it seems to be a bug in the kernel related to the old Matrox G200eR2 GPU. I found a link that addresses it. But the link is old and there seems to be no easy fix.